# Electron button has strange styling

Tags: html, css, macos, button, electron

For whatever reason my button's colors are stripped through, and I have not been able to find out why. I searched through the computed results but the border colors are set as one with no sign of weird settings. What am I doing wrong? Is this a MacOS issue?

[image: Weird Button]

Just noticed its happening to my HR tag too!

[image: DUMB HR TAG]

---

---

Here is the code for my HR and Button tags:

```
hr {
    /* Size & Position */
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    /* Borders */
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: #F4F7F5;
    /* Background */

    /* Font */
}

button{  
    /* Size & Position */
    margin: 10px;
    /* Borders */
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #033F63;
    /* Background */
    background-color: #F4F7F5;
    /* Font */
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    color: #373E40;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [border style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) property - specifically the value of _outset_.

Comment: Life saver! @chazsolo | I am not used to the user agent making changes like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user agent by default applied the outset value to the border style causing me to have this issue.